# Print out entire table with column names

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

I am currently learning SQL and am using MS SQL Server 2017.

I am able to print out a specific table with all the data except the column names and I don't really know how to retrieve them.

Here are parts of my code (I removed the try catch for the code sample)

```
Connection conn = null;
ResultSet rs = null;
String query = "SELECT * FROM Example";
ResultSetMetaData rsmd = null;

Class.forName(driver);
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl, userName, password);
Statement mS = conn.createStatement();
System.out.println("Verbindung wurde hergestellt");
rs = mS.executeQuery(query);
rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
int columnsNumber = rsmd.getColumnCount();
while (rs.next()) {
    for(int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
        System.out.print(rs.getString(i)+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

**EDIT:**
I want them to be printed out only once so that I have some kind of "header"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should start with a loop to print [rsmd.getColumnLabel(int column)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnLabel(int)) for each column index .

```
// header
    for(int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
        System.out.print(rsmd.getColumnLabel(i)+ " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

// data
    while(rs.next()) {
        for(int i = 1; i <= columnsNumber; i++) {
            System.out.print(rs.getString(i)+ " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: Okay, that works, but is it possible to retrieve these only once so that I have them as a "header"

Comment: Sure, just put this loop before your `while (rs.next())` loop and you're done (see the edited answer).